# Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int

Tags: java

I had the following lines of code

```
long longnum = 555L;
int intnum = 5;
intnum+=longnum;
intnum= intnum+longnum; //Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int
System.out.println("value of intnum is: "+intnum);
```

I think line-3 and line-4 do same task, 
then why compiler showing error on line-4 "Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int"

please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because the compound assignment operator does implicit casting.

From [JLS Compound Assignment Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

While in case of binary `+` operator, you have to do casting explicitly. Make your 4th assignment:

```
intnum = (int)(intnum+longnum);
```

and it would work. This is what your compound assignment expression is evaluated to.

Answer (score 11):

> I think line-3 and line-4 do same task, then why compiler showing error on line-4 "Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int"

Because they *don't* do the same thing. Compound assignment operators have an implicit cast in them.

From [section 15.26.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

So your third line is more like:

```
intnum = (int) (intnum + longnum);
```

The cast is required because in the expression `intnum + longnum`, [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) is applied before addition is performed in `long` arithemtic, with a result of `long`. There's no implicit conversion from `long` to `int`, hence the cast.

Comment: An answer from the Master!

Comment: Master maybe, but Rohit typed it 17 seconds faster.  A bit of a mystery why he doesn't have as many upvotes for an identical answer.  I guess the Skeet effect kicked in.

Answer (score 0):

```
Long id = 50;
Integer sum = Integer.valueOf(Long.toString(id));
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and format it so that it could be well understood.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.